# Temporarily use another older iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, apple-id, data-transfer

I currently have an iPhone 12. [redacted] have a old iPhone 8. Their iPhone exhibits some weird behavior and is becoming slow so they want to upgrade to a newer phone. The current plan is for them to use my iPhone 12 and for me to purchase a new iPhone 14 (Pro, if it comes with USB 3.0 lightning).

I will be travelling and staying in the US in August. They will travel with me, but travel back before September. Therefore, there won't be enough time for me to purchase a new iPhone 14 and give my old phone to them. Our current plan is for me to temporarily use their iPhone 8 while I wait for the release of the new iPhone 14. I plan to do this by backuping my iPhone 12 and restoring it to their iPhone 8, and vice versa.

Knowing that the two iPhones cross many generations and use different biometric authentication (Face ID vs Touch ID), what problems may occur by doing this? Specifically:

- Will confidential data, like health data, be lost?
- Will I have to log in to Apple ID again? Will this mess up
  trusted device and iCloud?
- Will applications that requires my Face ID for certain privileged tasks no longer work?
- Will applications require me to login again or setup again, especially for 2FA apps like Duo and Google Authenticator?

Answer (score 1):

> Knowing that the two iPhones cross many generations and use different biometric authentication (Face ID vs Touch ID), what problems may occur by doing this?

iPhone 12 and later support 5G frequency bands which are unavailable in the previous generations. As long as you are able to activate over and use previous generation cellular network, you should be fine.

Both iPhone 12 and iPhone 8 can run the current latest version of iOS, so make sure to update to the latest version of iOS (iOS 15.5 as of this writing) before backing up your iPhone 12 and also upgrade iPhone 8 to use the same.

Another thing to note is to check if the backup size is reasonably under the storage size of iPhone 8 and as that would ensure that you will be able to restore the backup onto it.

The above are the major considerations to keep in mind and you'd be fine. To answer your specific questions:

> - Will confidential data, like health data, be lost?

No. Make sure you have iCloud sync enabled for Health app.

> - Will I have to log in to Apple ID again? Will this mess up trusted device and iCloud?

While Apple ID login isn't required to use the phone functionality, it's recommend if you are looking at restoring all the data such as Contacts, Health and iCloud data onto the iPhone 8.

I don't understand what you mean by messing up trusted device and iCloud, but this exercise should remove iPhone 12 from the list of devices associated with your Apple ID and add iPhone 8 to the list.

> Will applications that requires my Face ID for certain privileged tasks no longer work?

The apps that rely on biometric authentication would use Touch ID as authentication mechanism instead of Face ID. You would need to set them up again on your iPhone 8, but once done, they'd work fine and it won't matter if you authenticate via Touch ID.

Do not consider Touch ID or Face ID to be inferior/superior to one another or having more/less features. Think about them as alternate means of authentication with them having their own pros and cons in terms of usage and convenience. (Touch ID works even with a face mask/covering on and more than one member can register their fingers, but may fail to work if you have wet fingers. Face ID can be more seamless on the other hand).

> - Will applications require me to login again or setup again, especially for 2FA apps like Duo and Google Authenticator?

Yes. But please note that if you have a 2FA code generator app such as Google Authenticator installed on your iPhone 12, you may lose access to the codes when attempting to restore the Google Authenticator app onto iPhone 8. A workaround that I use is to either disable 2FA on all the websites added into Google Authenticator, or regenerate the codes in an app such as 1Password that saves the data on cloud.

Comment: By "messing up trusted device and iCloud", I mean that my iPhone 12 is a 2FA device for my Apple ID, while their iPhone 8 is a 2FA device for their Apple ID. So does the 2FA rely on the device hardware or the software (data)?

Comment: So there could potentially be a conflict between the software saying that it's my iPhone while the Apple server thinks that the hardware is their iPhone, causing problems.

Comment: And by "lose access to the codes when attempting to restore the Google Authenticator app onto iPhone 8", do you mean that it will no longer generate codes and I need to link my account again? So I should disable 2FA first, and then link it again as if I have never setup 2FA.